# Is a mnemonic for view only wallet possible?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mnemonic-seed, cryptography, wallet-recovery, elliptic-curve

It occurred to me that one may wish to restore a wallet on a compromised computer.  Perhaps they need to prove that a payment was received.

Regardless of whether this is a good idea, is it possible to use a mnemonic to restore a view-only wallet, in terms of:

1. the required math to create a mnemonic for a deterministic viewkey, and
2. the code currently in place that parses and processes a mnemonic to create a wallet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monero's existing mnemonic scheme simply translates back and forth between a 32 byte scalar and a 25-word checksummed mnemonic.

At the moment, that's used to store the 32 byte seed. There is no reason it can't be used to produce a mnemonic from the 32 byte private view key.

However, you need to know both your private view key and your public spend key in order to create a view-only wallet.

Therefore you'd have to store both the mnemonic and your public spend key (or your wallet address, which contains your public spend key). If stored separately, your public spend key could be represented as base-58, hex, or as a second 25-word mnemonic.